# Multiple MQ listeners not working

Tags: c#, listener, ibm-mq, mq

I am trying to connect from my C# code to IBM MQ.

Callback works for one listener (listening to a queue). i.e. when a message comes to the queue, callback method is correctly invoked.

I created another queue#2 on the same QueueManager / Channel. Registered a new listener on this queue with a different callback method. No errors are observed during server startup.

When a message arrives at this queue#2, callback associated with the first queue is invoked and not the one that I have registered for this queue. I tried by creating a different session, and also a different connection, but still the behaviour is the same.

Does anybody have any ideas?

```
class Program
  {
     static void Main(string[] args)
      {
           string env = "DEV"
    string queueName1= "Queue1"
    string queueName2 = "Queue2"

    new MyListener(CallbackHandler1.onMessage1, env, queueName1).RegisterListener();

    new MyListener(CallbackHandler2.onMessage2, env, queueName2).RegisterListener();
         }



  public class MyListener
  {
public delegate void Handler (IMessage msg)
public static Handler _handler

private string env = "";
private string queue = "";

public MyListner(Handler _handler, string environment, string queueName)
{
     _handler = _handler;
      this.env = environment;
      this.queue = queueName
}

public void RegisterListener()
{

    XMSFactoryFactory xff = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
    IConnectionFactory cf = xff.CreateConnectionFactory();
    cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "10.87.188.156(7111)");
    cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, 7111);
    cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, "QMEIGS1.CRM.SVRCONN");
    cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT_UNMANAGED);
    cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "QMEIGS1");

    IConnection conn = cf.CreateConnection();
    Console.WriteLine("connection created");
    ISession sess = conn.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge);
    IDestination dest = sess.CreateQueue(queue);
    IMessageConsumer consumer = sess.CreateConsumer(dest);
    MessageListener ml = new MessageListener(OnMessage);
    consumer.MessageListener = ml;
    conn.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Consumer started");

}

private void onMessage(IMessage m)
{
    try {
        _handler(m)
        }
    catch (Exception e ) 
    {
    }
}
}


  //callback 1
  public class CallbackHandler1

  public static void onMessage1(IMessage msg)
     {
   ITextMessage textMessage = IMessage(msg)
  // code to perform onmessage1
     }


  //callback 2
  public class CallbackHandler2

     public static void onMessage2(IMessage msg)
     {
  ITextMessage textMessage = IMessage(msg)
  // code to perform onmessage2
     }
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors? How are your channels defined?  What version of MQ are you using?  To use MQCB on a V7 client you must be connected to a V7 server and the SHARECNV parameter of the channel must have a non-zero value.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Your queues are not actually called queue#1 and queue#2 are they?

Comment: @Valerie, No, there are no errors at this stage. The first listener callback gets the message  (while I am expecting the second one to get this). Yes, ours is a v7 instance. I am not aware of the value of SHARECNV parameter value. Will check and come back.

Comment: @Morag,  no, they are not. That was just an easy way of explaining the problem without explaining the huge business context.

Comment: Can you unregister message listener for queue#1 and check if messages from queue #2 are received by message listener #2? You can also try by connection.stop() on first connection and check if messages are delivered to second message listener.

Comment: @Shashi, If I remove one listener, the second listener consumes from the second queue. Issue is when I have multiple listeners.

Comment: @Valerie, Is SHARECNV a server level property? Can I set this via code?  I have tried setting 
XMSC_WMQ_SHARE_CONV_ALLOWED_TRUE in the connection factory, but no luck.  Unfortunately, I don't have access to view server level properties.

Comment: I second Shashi's request to see the code

Comment: SHARECNV is a parameter setting in the channel definition on the queue manager.

Comment: @Shashi, Please find the code attached

Answer (score 0):

I am not a hardcore c# programmer but I think the problem is because of the `static` keyword in `public static Handler _handler;`. The keyword `static` makes only one instance of _`handler` available across all instances of a `MyListener` class. Although you are creating two consumers and assigning two listeners, the second call to assign the message listener is overwriting the first listener. Hence you are receiving messages from only one queue.

I modified your code little bit as it was not compiling and got it working after removing the `static` keyword. I used MQ v8 for compiling the program. But the version should not be a problem for you.

```
namespace multilistener
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string env = "DEV";
            string queueName1= "SUB.Q";
            string queueName2 = "SUB.Q1";

        new MyListener(CallbackHandler1.onMessage1, env, queueName1).RegisterListener();

        new MyListener(CallbackHandler2.onMessage2, env, queueName2).RegisterListener();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
        Console.WriteLine("Program ends");
     }
}

public class MyListener
{
    public delegate void Handler (IMessage msg);
    public Handler _handler; // Remove 'static' keyword

    private string env = "";
    private string queue = "";

    public MyListener(Handler _Inhandler, string environment, string queueName)
    {
        _handler = _Inhandler;
        this.env = environment;
        this.queue = queueName;
    }

    public void RegisterListener()
    {
        try
        {

            XMSFactoryFactory xff = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
            IConnectionFactory cf = xff.CreateConnectionFactory();
            cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "localhost");
            cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, 1414);
            cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, "MY.SVRCONN");
            cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.USERID, "userid");
            cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.PASSWORD, "password");
            cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "QM1");

            IConnection conn = cf.CreateConnection();
            Console.WriteLine("connection created");
            ISession sess = conn.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge);
            IDestination dest = sess.CreateQueue(queue);
            IMessageConsumer consumer = sess.CreateConsumer(dest);
            MessageListener ml = new MessageListener(onMessage);
            consumer.MessageListener = ml;
            conn.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Consumer started");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    private void onMessage(IMessage m)
    {
        try {
            _handler(m);
        }
        catch (Exception e ) 
        {
            Console.Write(e);
        }
    }
}


//callback 1
public class CallbackHandler1
{
    public static void onMessage1(IMessage msg)
    {
        ITextMessage textMessage = (ITextMessage)msg;
        // code to perform onmessage1
        Console.WriteLine("First consumer");
    }
}

//callback 2
public class CallbackHandler2
{
    public static void onMessage2(IMessage msg)
    {
        ITextMessage textMessage = (ITextMessage)msg;
        // code to perform onmessage2
        Console.WriteLine("Second consumer");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: @Sasi, I tried with removing the static keyword and the issue still remains. I have also tried creating two separate listener classes, with onMessage implemented for each listener, but when a message arrives at this queue#2, callback associated with the first queue is invoked and not the one that I have registered for the second queue.  I am using MQ client 7.0 and .NET 2012

Comment: Also can see that getting below Exception while executing the program. System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
FFDC to xmsffdc9664_2015.10.10T19.51.02.290535.txt

Unhandled Exception: IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiException: Exception of type 'IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiException' was thrown.
   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.UnmanagedNmqiMQ.NmqiConsumerMethodUM(Int32 hconn, IntPtr structMqmd, IntPtr structMqgmo, IntPtr buffer, IntPtr structMqcbc)

Comment: @Valarie, SHARECNV is configured as 1,  and I tried changing to 2 , 5, 10 etc.. But didn't work.

Comment: MQ v7.0/7.0.1 went out of support end of September 2015. I suggest you to upgrade MQ client to v7.1 and test. If problem persists, open a ticket with IBM.